# I want to create Authentication with Spring Security ! And I have this ERROR

Tags: spring, spring-boot

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

```
Field userService in com.rizomm.filemanager.server.controllers.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'com.rizomm.filemanager.business.services.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.rizomm.filemanager.business.services.UserService' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Have you `annotated` `com.rizomm.filemanager.business.services.UserService` class with `@Component`?

Comment: No, why ? I annotated with @Service

Comment: `@Service` is also fine. Can u post main class? It might be package scanning issue.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.rizomm.filemanager"})
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.rizomm.filemanager"})
public class FilemanagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FilemanagerApplication.class, args);
    }
}